# Getting error while using Sitecore Content Search with Lucene while returning single item

Tags: c#, linq, lucene, sitecore, sitecore7

I'm working on blog migration from Wordpress to Sitecore 7.2 & wrote a script in c# to create items.
To prevent the duplicate items,I created an extension method to check if we already have item.

```
/// <summary>
/// Check if item with given name exists as child & if yes,return that item
/// </summary>
/// <returns></returns>
public static Item GetItemIfExists(this Item parentItem, string itemName)
{
  Item childItem = null;

  using (var context = Constants.Index.CreateSearchContext())
  {
     childItem = context.GetQueryable<SearchResultItem>().Where(i => i.Path.Contains(parentItem.Paths.FullPath) && i.Name == itemName).Select(i => (Item)i.GetItem()).FirstOrDefault();
  }

  return childItem;
}
```

This method uses Sitecore's content search functionality,but throws following  error:

> Wrong type: System.Linq.IQueryable`1[[Sitecore.Data.Items.Item,
>   Sitecore.Kernel, Version=7.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=null]]. Expected:
>   System.Linq.IQueryable`1[[Sitecore.ContentSearch.SearchTypes.SearchResultItem,
>   Sitecore.ContentSearch, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=null]]

While,if I modify the method as follow,it works fine:

```
            /// <summary>
            /// Check if item with given name exists as child & if yes,return that item
            /// </summary>
            /// <returns></returns>
            public static Item GetItemIfExists(this Item parentItem, string itemName)
            {
                var childItem = new List<Item>();

                using (var context = Constants.Index.CreateSearchContext())
                {
                    childItem = context.GetQueryable<SearchResultItem>().Where(i => i.Path.Contains(parentItem.Paths.FullPath) && i.Name == itemName).Select(i => (Item)i.GetItem()).ToList();
                }

                return childItem.FirstOrDefault();
            }
```

What's the best way to return single item from Sitecore's content search?

Answer (score 0):

Try using `.Where(i => i.Path.Contains(parentItem.Paths.FullPath) && i.Name == itemName).Take(1).ToList()`

Remember the query is assembled before it is enumerated so as soon as you call ToList or Select the query is sent to the search index and enumerated, from that point on you cannot modify the query (as it has already been sent), so the order of your linq statements is important.

You can see in the example we call the `Take()` (to limit the call) before enumerating.

You can look in the `search.log' in your`logs` directory to see the difference between the queries too.

If you have used LinqPad before I would recommend ([Adam Conn's LinqPad Connector for Sitecore ContentSearch](http://www.sitecore.net/Community/Technical-Blogs/Getting-to-Know-Sitecore/Posts/2014/06/LINQPad-Driver-for-Sitecore-Version-1_5.aspx)) it will allow you to experiment with linq queries against your own search index.